# Unbiased Estimator of the Standard Deviation of the Sample Standard Deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, sample, unbiased-estimator

I'm looking for an unbiased estimator of the standard deviation $\text{SD}(s)$ of the sample standard deviation $s = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \overline{x})^2}$.
I have found [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/28567/178794) which is highly relevant to this question, however, I would prefer a solution that does not assume normality (similarly to the [unbiased estimator of the variance of the sample variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/307537/unbiased-estimator-of-the-variance-of-the-sample-variance)).

Is there a general solution for non-normal distributions?

Comment: Probably for particular families of distributions there are such estimators but for all probability distributions in general, or even for all with finite moments, I suspect there is none.

Comment: My impression is that we either have yet to find one that works as broadly as $S^2$ does for variance (e.g., specific to the normal distribution) or that we have shown that no such estimator can exist. I am, however, unsure which of those is correct.