# What is the variance of $s^2$?

Tags: variance, estimation, sample, consistency

I am trying to calculate the variance of $s^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum (x_i-\bar x)^2$. So what I want to find is $ Var(s^2)$.

I have seen different posts, but many of them seem to make the assumption that the population is normally distributed. I don't know anything about the distribution.

Can anyone help or guide me in the right direction?

Comment: You can find the general formula in many questions: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72975/variance-of-sample-variance) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/307537/unbiased-estimator-of-the-variance-of-the-sample-variance) for example.

Comment: Thx! I have seen the first example before, and that is also what the second is referencing. I don't quite seem to understand it though. Especially the first part where he rewrites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variance of s^2 if the population is non-Normal in case of simple random sampling, is

```
       Var(s^2) = (1 / n)[μ4 - μ2^2(n - 3) / (n -1)]
```

If the population is Normal, then μ4 = 3σ^4, and μ2^2 = σ4. So, we get

```
                  Var(s^2) = 2σ^4 / (n - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Please accept the solution, If this works for you  @chri344v