# Unconditional Variance of square term

Tags: time-series, econometrics

Is there any way to calculate unconditional variance of $X_{t-1}^2$ i.e. (VAR($X_{t-1}^2$)), when X follows an AR(1) process, $X_t = \phi X_{t-1} + e_t$ with VAR(X) being $\sigma_v^2$ and the mean of the error term is E($e_t$)= 0?

Comment: Not in general, because it depends on unspecified properties of the distribution of $e_t.$  Do you make a specific assumption about that distribution, such as being Gaussian for instance?

Comment: No not as such but say If I assume a Gaussian distribution, then what would be its answer ?

Comment: Apply, for instance, the formula at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/628048.